# The parameter can't have a value of "null" - error

Tags: flutter, dart

[image]

I don't know how to resolve this error, i try to set the parameter how nnull parameter with 'String? assetImage' but continue to retrivies an error, how can i resolve this ?

Comment: Don't post text as image

Comment: But if it is a url which type is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove the `@` in every `@required`

```dart
MyCard({required this.assetImage, ...});
```

[more info](https://dart.dev/null-safety/migration-guide)